# How to download lmfit on Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, lmfit

I ran this on the Anaconda Prompt to install **lmfit**:

```
conda install -c conda-forge lmfit
```

However when I type:

```
import lmfit
```

I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lmfit'

Why does Python not recognize that I downloaded lmfit?

Comment: lmfit is on conda-forge, so I think that should work.  Does it show up with `conda list`? Does lmfit work if you install it from the GSECARS channel?  If not, you may want to look in your site-packages directory or try to figure out where it did get installed and/or how your python path is set up.

Answer (score 2):

Try to swipe up the channel of the package:`conda-forge` by `GSECARS`, like:

```
conda install -c GSECARS lmfit
```

hope that helps

Comment: I still get this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lmfit'

Comment: It has been figured out. You need to type "jupyter notebook" in the anaconda prompt. Then you can import lmfit.